# How to check if a class implements a interface

Tags: java, interface, implements

here we go,

I have an marker interface :

```
interface IPOJO {
}
```

And then i have a class implementing this interface :

```
class MePOJO implements IPOJO {
}
```

Now suppose i have a `class object` holding reference of class MePOJO :

```
Class<MePOJO> classObj = MePOJO.class;
```

So how can i determine if `MePOJO` class implements `IPOJO` just by using `classObj` ?

Comment: why not simply use the keyword `instanceof` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method here:

```
Class<?> classObj = MePOJO.class;
System.out.println(IPOJO.class.isAssignableFrom(classObj));
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Also works: `IPOJO.class.isAssignableFrom(MePOJO.class))`

Comment: @c.s.. Yup that would also work. `classObj` is nothing but `MePOJO.class` only.

Answer (score 5):

There are several approaches for this.

***Either*** by using the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type of the object you've created and retrieve the list with all the interfaces that it implements.

```
MePOJO test = new MePOJO();
Class[] interfaces = test.getClass().getInterfaces();
for (Class c : interfaces) {
   if ("IPOJO".equals(c.getSimpleName()) {
      System.out.println("test implements IPOJO");
   }
}
```

Or using the [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class clazz)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method:

```
Class<?> clazz = MePOJO.class;
System.out.println(IPOJO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz));
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but for the sake of completeness, [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces())

Comment: Note that `OP` is having `Class<?>` object, and not an instance of `MePOJO`, so this isn't right answer at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer and summarized several possible approaches.

Comment: I believe you should remove the first option since OP does not specify if MePOJO class has a default constructor or not. In the second option creating a new instance is not required. You can just do `MePOJO.class.getInterfaces();`

Comment: Careful with `getInterfaces()` it does different things than `instanceof`: http://ideone.com/nAmEyO

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is not with marker interfaces at all but with annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public static @interface Pojo {
}

@Pojo
public static class MePojo {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(MePojo.class.isAnnotationPresent(Pojo.class));
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

This way you don't pollute the namespace with marker interfaces.

Comment: Depends on what you intend to do with those markings. If you want to limit methods that could take any `Object` to take only marked ones it's easier to let them implement an interface since you get compile time errors instead of having to check at runtime whether they have an annotation. `Serializable` for example.

Comment: I don't think that's a marker interface then because inheritance applies. You only want to accept `Foo`. A marker interface is, by definition, outside of inheritance.

Comment: Hmm, if you define it that way, +1

Answer (score 2):

Check with  the keyword  `instanceOf`

```
if(classObj  instanceOf IPOJO ){

}
```

> The [instanceof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) operator evaluates to true if and only if the runtime type of the object is assignment compatible with the class or interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are also class members that allow you to get the names of the super class of the object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Answer (score 1):

Use method isInstance from Class :

```
if (classObj.isInstance(myObj)){
     ...
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html